# SELECT return one word per result from a single DB row

Tags: mysql

I have a DB table with the columns `id` and `alias`

```
id    | alias
------|------------------
1     | green
2     | red maroon sunset
3     | blue navy
```

I need to get a list of single tags, i.e. `SELECT ... FROM color` that returns the results in the form like this:

```
1 => green
2 => red
2 => maroon
2 => sunset
3 => blue
3 => navy
```

Is there a way to split/ungroup the alias values directly in SQL? What's the best way for this without changing the DB structure (and code)?

**Update**

Unfortunately it's a system that cannot be changed easily and we do not have the resources to rewrite all connected systems/APIs... so maybe someone knows about a good/working solution for this situation.

Comment: You actually should change the DB structure. Your table is not normalized. Never store multiple values in a single column!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm aware that a different DB structure would be the best solution. Unfortunately we do not have the option to modify the DB in this case (the example above is simplified and not the real DB content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a table of integers (0-9)...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,alias VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'green'),
(2,'red maroon sunset'),
(3,'blue navy');

SELECT DISTINCT x.id
              , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x.alias,' ',i.i+1),' ',-1) alias 
           FROM my_table x
              , ints i -- my integers table
          ORDER 
             BY id
              , i;
+----+--------+
| id | alias  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | green  |
|  2 | red    |
|  2 | maroon |
|  2 | sunset |
|  3 | blue   |
|  3 | navy   |
+----+--------+
```